# return JSON value out of function?

Tags: jquery, function, google-geocoder

I'm trying to return a `lat` value out of a function using Google's Geocoder, but it's not working. I'm getting an error that says "unexpected token"?

```
function getLat(address) {
  var googleToken = "my-google-token"
  var geoUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&key=" + googleToken;
    $.getJSON(geoUrl, function(data) {
      return data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
    });
}

$('body').html(getLat('New+York,+NY'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is loading an external resource using an `XMLHTTPRequest` is an async task.

Better and easy way of doing this is

```
function getLat(address, $el, type) {
  var googleToken = "my-google-token"
  var geoUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&key=" + googleToken;
    $.getJSON(geoUrl, function(data) {
      if(type=="html")
         $el.html(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
      else if(type=="text")
         $el.text(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
    });
}

getLat('New+York,+NY', $("body"), "html");
getLat('New+York,+NY', $("div"), "text");
```

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: couldn't you now remove the `return`?

Comment: Can you tell me the output of the geoUrl?

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a way to call this in other functions, such as `$('div').text(getLat('New+York,+NY'));`. So this format wouldn't work great for me?

Comment: Check the updated code. It will work for you still :)!

Answer (score 1):

The async function needs a callback, or you can use promises

```
function getLat(address) {
    return $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
       adress : adress,
       key    : "my-google-token"
    });
}

getLat('New+York,+NY').done(function(data) {
    $('body').html(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
});
```